# Using custom object to get values + Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I am using an object to get value of RestAPI url details which contains the assets. The location is the region where the assets are present.

I am reading the location values using import-csv menthod and using a for loop

```
$inventory = Import-Csv "File.csv"

$output = foreach($i in $inventory){
    $RestAPIobject = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -uri "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

    $CBObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject

    $CBObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Region-Value $i.region
    $CBObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Assets -Value $RestAPIobject.name
    
    $CBObject
}
```

I am getting the output as :-

```
Location  Assets                                                                                                                       
Region1   {H1, H2, H3}
Region2   {A1, A2}
```

whereas I want the output as

```
Location  Assets                                                                                                                          
Region1   H1
Region1   H2
Region1   H3
Region2   A1
Region2   A2
```

Comment: Your code outputs a `CB` member, but the output lists a `Assets` column instead. Is this the real code you are running?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output, it appears that `$RestAPIobject.name` contains *multiple values*.

Change your code to:

```
$inventory = Import-Csv "File.csv"

$output = foreach($i in $inventory){
    $RestAPIobject = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -uri "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

    foreach($name in $RestAPIobject.name){
        $CBObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject
        $CBObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Location -Value $i.location
        $CBObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CB -Value $name
    
        $CBObject
    }
}
```

---

Unless you intend for your script to be working with PowerShell 2.0, I'd recommend using the `[PSCustomObject]` object initializer syntax (introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0):

```
foreach($name in $RestAPIobject.name){
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Location = $i.location
        CB       = $name
    }
}
```

Much simpler syntax and a bit faster than `New-Object` + `Add-Member`

Comment: No I am using Powershell 5.1

Comment: @DishantDhokia Then the `[PSCustomObject]@{...}` syntax will work perfectly fine for you

Comment: How will u add more values in output if RestAPIobject has many objects

id                      
name                    
status                           
details  

as teh current for loop will only have name

Comment: @DishantDhokia If `$RestAPIobject` is an array: `foreach($object in $RestAPIobject){ [pscustomobject]@{ Name = $object.name; ID = $object.id <# and so on ... #>}}`